# Bash script to find file older than X days, then subsequently delete it, and any files with the same base name?

Tags: bash

I am trying to figure out a way to search a directory for a file older than 365 days. If it finds a match, I'd like it to both delete the file and locate any other files in the directory that have the same basename, and delete those as well.

File name examples: 12345.pdf (Search for) then delete, 12345_a.pdf, 12345_xyz.pdf (delete if exist).

Thanks! I am very new to BASH scripting, so patience is appreciated ;-))

Comment: did you try anything with the find command with -mtime +365 option with basename and rm in xargs ?

Comment: @NSD how will they delete all files with the same basename?

Comment: @MiserableVariable , the same way you did ... i didnt give the answer , just wanted to drop a hint so that he could try once....

Comment: Hmm..I missed the basename/xargs stuff in your comment previously

Comment: my attempt would have been something like this :: `for fls in find . -iname "z*" -exec  basename  {} \; | cut -d"." -f1 ; do find . -iname "*$fls*" | xargs ls -l; done ;`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this can be done cleanly in a single pass.

Your best bet is to use `-mtime` or a variant to collect names and then use another `find` command to delete files matching those names.

**UPDATE**

With respect to your comment, I mean something like:

```
# find basenames of old files
find .... -printf '%f\n' | sort -u > oldfiles
for file in ($<oldfiles); do find . -name $file -exec rm; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am using find /data/.../.../departments/yyy-mtime +365 -exec rm {} \;
to delete the file. I'm not sure how to reuse the found file name to search for other files with matching basename.....